# Display the total count of an item and its parent using PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, count, logic

Need help displaying the correct count of an item and its parent on the first item added.

**Problem:** Right now everything works **UNLESS** there is only one comment made on an item. If there is only one comment made it displays that there are 2 comments instead of one which is not correct.

I am displaying the **total count** of all comments (users can reply to a comment so I need to count the parent message) It all works **UNLESS** the count is 1. If the count is 1 it prints out that there are 2 comments and not 1. (So if there is only one comment and no one has replyed to the comment and made another comment the number still shows 2) How would I go about fixing this? Is something wrong with my  I am confusing myself so figured I would just submit a question. This is my first question I have ever asked on here. See my code below. Let me know if I need to include more information

---

```
<?php if (!empty($comments)) : ?>
   <?php foreach($comments as $pid => $parent_messages) : ?>
      <?php $comments_count = (count($comments)) + (count($parent_messages)); ?>//this may be where I am creating the problem of displaying 2 even if there is 1 comment made
      <span class="badge pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><?php ($comments_count != 0)  ? print ' '.$comments_count.' comments' : ''; ?></span>
   <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate Mate. Whats the actual problem

Comment: If there's only one comment then `$parent_messages` should be an empty array. There's probably a flaw in you code. Fix that and you won't need any other if statement

Comment: Okay, Let me try to elaborate. I need to display the number of comments made on an item. The problem is right now when there is only one comment made on an item it says that there are 2 comments(which is not correct because there is only one). All other instances work unless there is only one comment on the item.

Comment: @Capsule this makes sense to me.. do you think my error is in my sql or in the code i pasted above

Comment: It's not in the code above. I think `count($parent_messages)` equals one (should be 0)  when `count($comments)` equals one, hence ending up with 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: @Capsule Thanks, you are right.. my problem is I just don't know how to change it so that count($parent_messages) equals 0 instead of 1

Comment: Me neither since your question doesn't show how you obtain it.